# Converting NAN values to a custom value by selecting some columns in multi-index df

Tags: python, pandas

I have a multi-index dataframe that looks something this (however more Year values):

```
                          week_13 week_14 week_15 week_16  week_17  
Year                                                                
2018 San Francisco 49ers   winner  winner   loser   loser      NaN  
     Seattle Seahawks      winner   loser  winner  winner      NaN  
     Tampa Bay Buccaneers  loser   loser   loser   loser       NaN  
     Tennessee Titans       NaN      NaN   winner   loser      NaN  
     Washington Redskins    loser  winner   loser   loser      NaN
```

I want to be able change all NAN values to 'winner' from `week_13` to `week_16` (not week_17)

I am attempting various ways, but none of the changes seem to be permanent.

```
#impermanent
df.isnull()["week_13" : 'week_17'] =1
df.loc[df.isnull()]["week_13" : 'week_17'] =1
```

How should I go about converting the Nan (week_13 and week_14) to 'winner'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The canonical way is to use `df.fillna('winner')` on the specific columns whose null values you wish to replace. This should work:

```
cols = [f'week_{x}' for x in range(14, 17)]
df.loc[:, cols] = df.loc[:, cols].fillna('winner')
```

Alternatively, to `fillna` every column except the rightmost (last) column:

```
df.iloc[:, :-1] = df.iloc[:, :-1].fillna('winner')
```

Comment: This seems to work. Just an additional question regarding your code:
If I want to find the indices of the null values, I thought this would work:
`df[df.iloc[:,:-1].isnull()].index.tolist()` because I am using boolean indexing to pull out a subset of the dataframe. However, it returns all indices.